# function analysis combination of two linear bounded functional

Tags: functional-analysis

The operators and functionals considered in the text are defined on the entire space $X$. Show that without that assumption, in the case of functionals we still have the following theorem. If $f$ and $g$ are bounded linear functionals with domains in a normed space $X$, then for any nonzero scalars $a$ and $b$ the linear combination $h = a f + b g$ is a bounded linear functional with domain intersection of their domains

Comment: Would you mind accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Even though not required here, the quickest way is to invoke the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Extend $f$ and $g$ to bounded functionals $F$, $G$, respectively, on the entire space and note that $h = (aF + bG)|_{{\rm dom}\, f \cap {\rm dom\, g}}$. A restriction of a bounded map is bounded.

Comment: Do we know that $f,g$ have closed domain?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets, irrelevant here.

Comment: You are completely right :)

Comment: I am not the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \operatorname{dom}f \cap \operatorname{dom}g$, then $||f(x)|| \leq ||f|| \cdot ||x||$ and $||g(x)|| \leq ||g|| \cdot ||x||$ as $f,g$ are bounded and $x$ is n their domains
$$||h(x)|| = ||af(x) + bg(x)|| \leq a ||f(x)|| + b||g(x)|| \leq a||f|| \cdot ||x|| + b||g|| \cdot ||x|| = (a||f|| + b||g||) ||x||.$$
Hence $h$ is bounded on $\operatorname{dom}f \cap \operatorname{dom}g$ and $||h|| \leq a ||f|| + b ||g||$ there.